# Django: Why am I getting ValueError when referring to a ForeignKey using a varchar?

Tags: django

My application (called users) includes these two models:

```
class RankingType(models.Model):
    type_code = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.description}'


class RankingProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        to_field='username',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='ranking_profile_as_user',
        blank=False
    )
    type_code = models.ForeignKey(
        RankingType,
        to_field='type_code',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='ranking_profile_as_type',
        blank=False,
        default='btb_buyer'
    )
    profile_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    price_weight = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    transhipment_weight = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    earliest_etd_weight = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    latest_eta_weight = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.profile_name}'
```

makemigrations and migrate work fine.  I then run some code that loads the users_rankingtype table from a CSV and then users_rankingprofile from another CSV.

The users_rankingtype table loads without problem, but when I try to run the code that loads the users_rankingprofile it fails on the first insertion with a ValueError:

```
Cannot assign "'btb_buyer'": "RankingProfile.type_code" must be a "RankingType" instance.
```

Here's the code that loads the table:

```
    file_in = path + 'users_rankingprofile.csv'
    count_rankingprofile = 0
    with open(file_in) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            r = RankingProfile(
                profile_name=row['profile_name'],
                price_weight=row['price_weight'],
                transhipment_weight=row['transhipment_weight'],
                earliest_etd_weight=row['earliest_etd_weight'],
                type_code=row['type_code'],
                username=row['username'],
                latest_eta_weight=row['latest_eta_weight'],
            )
            r.save()
            count_rankingprofile = count_rankingprofile + 1
```

I use PyCharm, and so I can inspect the RankingType table.  The first row of the `users_rankingtype` table has `btb_buyer` in the `type_code` column is in the table.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks and regards...Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think changing the line `type_code=row['type_code']` to `type_code_id=row['type_code']` may solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks - that's exactly what it was.  Fixing that revealed another error in my coding - I needed to change ```username=row['username']``` to ```user_id=row['username']```.

Comment: No thank you, because with your question I learned how to use `ForeignKey` with `to_field` argument which I didn't know before.